# How do I add a "New" Python script option to the context menu?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7, contextmenu

I'm trying to add a context menu option for New -> Python Script on Windows 7. However, everything I've tried has failed.

The way that I thought it should work is below:

#### Add the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\ShellNew]
"FileName"="Template.py"
```

#### Null File version:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
```

#### Optional registry key

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
"PerceivedType"="text/plain"
@="Python Script"
```

#### Add the file to the Windows, ShellNew folder...

[image: Python template file in C:\Windows\ShellNew]

This does nothing, although I've done this before, and it worked with other file types. I'm unable to find anything for this anywhere, because they do everything I try for other file types.

What am I doing wrong?

## **EDIT: Python 2.7.8 or later has this option added during setup/installation.**

Reference: [MSDN Extending Shortcut Menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144101%28VS.85%29.aspx#new)

Comment: I think you should set `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python` to `"Python Script"`, not `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\PerceivedType="text"
```

together with

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\ShellNew\NullFile=""
```

works for me on Windows 7.

I have also set `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python` default value to `"Python Script"`

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
@="Python"
"Content Type"="text/x-python"
"Python"="Python"
"PerceivedType"="text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python]
@="Python Script"
```

Comment: Care to export your registry for those keys?

Answer (score 12):

I have found that the easiest way to do this is with the following method, which I have tested on my Windows 10 PC.

1. Open Regedit
2. Navigate to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.py
3. Right click on the .py key > New > Key
4. Name the new key "ShellNew"
5. Inside the ShellNew key, add a new string value
6. Name the string value "NullFile"
7. Change the NullFile's value to 1
8. That's it!

(note: this should work with all plain-text file formats)

Answer (score 0):

Use [open++](http://dengdun.webs.com/en/openxx.htm). It's easy to configure, and maybe it can do what you want.

Comment: That link is (effectively) broken now (*"We're sorry, this site is frozen. If you are the site owner, please [click here to contact us](http://dengdun.webs.com/en/openxx.htm#) regarding the status of your website."*).